# How to log the file using Log::Log4perl module in perl

Tags: perl

I am beginner in perl .I write the script for adding two number using
Getopt::Long module .I am facing difficulty to log the below script using Log::Log4perl module. Can anyone please help me with that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Log::Log4perl;
my $num1=<>;
my $num2=<>;
chomp($num1,$num2);
my $res=GetOptions("numone=i"=>\$num1,
"numtwo=i"=>\$num2);
my $add=$num1 + $num2;
print $add;
```

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: Why are you first reading the numbers from STDIN and then overwriting them with command line arguments (if given) by `GetOptions()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

my $conf = do { local $/; <DATA> };
Log::Log4perl::init( \$conf );
my $num1;
my $num2;
if (@ARGV == 0) {
    print "Enter number1: ";
    chomp($num1 = <>);
    INFO( "Read number1 from STDIN: '$num1'" );
    print "Enter number2: ";
    chomp($num2=<>);
    INFO( "Read number2 from STDIN: '$num2'" );
}
else {
    GetOptions("numone=i" =>\$num1, "numtwo=i"=>\$num2)
      or die "Bad command line options\n";
    die "Number1 undefined\n" if !defined $num1;
    die "Number2 undefined\n" if !defined $num2;
    INFO( "Read number1 from ARGV: '$num1'" );
    INFO( "Read number2 from ARGV: '$num2'" );
}
my $add = $num1 + $num2;
say "Result: $num1 + $num2 = $add";

__DATA__
log4perl.rootLogger=INFO, LOGFILE
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE=Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.filename=mylog.log
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.mode=append
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.layout=PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%r] %F %L %c - %m%n
```

Example session:

```
$ p.pl --numone=3 --numtwo=4
Result: 3 + 4 = 7
$ cat mylog.log
[0] ./p.pl 26 main - Read number1 from ARGV: '3'
[0] ./p.pl 27 main - Read number2 from ARGV: '4'
```